# How do I save a string Variable of a Class on the heap using new

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, constructor, new-operator

I have a problem,
I have to write a paper about Dynamic Memory Management in C++, however I never learned C++.

For my example code I want to show, why you need to use a Deconstructor if you allocate memory using new in your Class. But I can't get my code to work.
How do I write my Constructor, so that the string name gets allocated with the new operator?

Code i already have:

```
class Studi
{
private:                         
    unsigned int matNr;    
    char* name;            
    
public:
    Studi(const string& k_name, unsigned int k_matNr) 
    {
        name = new char[k_name.length()];
        strcpy(name, k_name);
        matNr = k_matNr;    
    }
};
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: fwiw, `std::string` does dynamic memory managment, its just not manual. If you write an essay about dynamic memory you don't want to miss that

Comment: About Constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp?view=msvc-160
About Destructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/destructors-cpp?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 4):

- You have to allocate one more byte for the terminating null-character.
- You can use [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to obtain C-style string from `std::string`.

```
    Studi(const string& k_name, unsigned int k_matNr) 
    {
        name = new char[k_name.length() + 1];
        strcpy(name, k_name.c_str());
        matNr = k_matNr;    
    }
```

Also don't forget to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to avoid memory management troubles when the object is copied.